# Where is the servletContext available in Grails?

Tags: java, grails, servlets

Where is the `servletContext` available in a Grails application? I tried to acces it in the `Config.groovy` but it didn't work. Access it in a view is also not possible.

I want to set the temp directory as the directory to store uploaded files in my development and test environment with `storage = (File)servletContext["javax.servlet.context.tempdir"]`.

Following Burt's advice I tried the following in conf/Config.groovy:

```
environments {
    production {
        grails.serverURL = "http://demo.com"
    }
    development {
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
        storageDir = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder
            .getServletContext()["javax.servlet.context.tempdir"]
    }
    test {
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
    }

}
```

... but get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'javax.servlet.context.tempd
ir' on null object
        at Config$_run_closure1_closure4.doCall(Config.groovy:59)
        at Config$_run_closure1_closure4.doCall(Config.groovy)
        at Config$_run_closure1.doCall(Config.groovy:57)
        at Config$_run_closure1.doCall(Config.groovy)
        at Config.run(Config.groovy:53)
        at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:52)
        at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure10.doCall(_GrailsPackage_g
roovy:93)
        at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure10.doCall(_GrailsPackage_g
roovy)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:2
80)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
        at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:92)
        at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:28)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Failed to compile configuration file: Cannot get property 'javax.servlet.context
.tempdir' on null object
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder.getServletContext()` if you're in code that doesn't already have access to it.

Comment: I've got the same problem. I need it in resource.groovy, but ServletContextHolder.getServletContext() returns null. grailsApplication.mainContext.servletContext doesn't work either, because mainContext doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it from any controler. You may be able to access it from bootstrap.groovy but I doubt it. For an example of accessing it from a controler see
http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/servletContext.html

Comment: A controller is much too late if you need it earlier, like in Config, or, in my case, in resource.groovy.